# Intel OpenCL: Tools for looking timeline of concurrent kernel execution

Tags: opencl, intel, nsight

In case of CUDA, NSIGHT would give us detail time lines of each kernel.

Is there similar tool for Intel Opencl? Basically I want to see if my three kernels are running in concurrently or not.

Comment: I know tools are great. But I find it easier and more portable to just do `cl::Event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_START>()` and `cl::Event.getProfilingInfo<CL_PROFILING_COMMAND_END>()`. And then print the 3 start values and ends, or simply check if the times overlap. Then you can even handle in the code itself situations were the HW supports overlap or it doesn't.

Comment: Nsight can trace OpenCL API calls. There is a checkbox for it in the tracing settings.